# I trust people, why should it change?

Tags: ethics, society, social-ethics, practical-ethics

I trust people.

For the small things in life, it helps me, definitely, but when it comes to larger things it is an issue.

For instance I recently started to search if I could buy a house. I am not rich so for me it means credit. So basically if somebody sells me something which is not honest he could put me under debt and therefore make my whole life very complicated.

Personally I don't want to change, I still want to trust that people naturally are honest.

When somebody tries to sell me something, why should I think: '*is it right?* *are you not trying to rip me off?*' instead of '*I believe this is the price of your work, let's see if we can accommodate it together*'

when somebody gives me something, why should I think: '*is it all right?* *am I not abusing his kindness?*' instead of '*Thank you! I trust what you give me does not cost to your life*'

when somebody ask for help, why should I think: '*could he be lying?* *is it just to abuse the kindness of people?* ' instead of '*If I feel good helping I will, otherwise I won't?*'

why should this change?

I am not looking for a personal opinion more for readings together with some quotes or references.

Thank you

**Edited with other examples**

Comment: "Why I Quit Being So Accomodating" (1922) https://mikecanex.wordpress.com/2012/12/26/1922-why-i-quit-being-so-accommodating/

Comment: @JosephWeissman: Thank you for the great reading, however being accommodating is very different than trust. In this example his was himself not honest with his life. For instance, if somebody is not nice, you should say it, if something hurts, you should say it. I say the truth, I trust others also say the truth. I will edited my answer with one more example.

Comment: Welcome to Philosophy.SE. Please take a moment to read through the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Why should you do anything? You have to give us something concerning your value system and cost/benefit calculus to finish the question. Obviously, people will take advantage of your trust, and you can get hurt, financially (as you yourself mention) or even physically. It may not bother you, or you may be willing to pay the price, but how would we know? You can look at [SEP's Trust](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/trust), but without specifics it is hard to recommend anything specific.

Comment: @Conifold The chapter 2 of the SEP answer my question in a with good references: Thank you for the useful link! (if the link is permanent, I can validate this as an answer) Regarding the value system: I am using as reference those who surround me, European citizen, not living in his own country, who has travelled quite few countries and though a lot of social classes. And regarding the cost/benefit: I would like to meet the expectation of people without damaging a proper life ethic.